# Illustrator pathfinder divide causes artifacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have 2 overlapping squares which I've rounded the corners on (so no longer squares :) ) by dragging the handle which rounds the corners. I want to overlap the shapes and divide them with the pathfinder. When I do this I get strange effects/artifacts "added" on the square beneath the top one. The artifact is not selectable and does not have any paths, nor does it show if I choose to save for web.

Any clues on how to solve this? My precision for pathfinder is set to 0.001

before divide operation

[image: image to illustrate problem]

after divide operation

[image: image to illustrate problem]

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a known problem which can be solved by turning off GPU Performance under illustrator performance preferences.
https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/gpu-glitch-in-illustrator-25-3-1-weird-corners-jagged-lines-weird-artifacts/m-p/12162860

However, for me that introduced another issue which makes the entire work area go gray when zooming in past 708% (in my case).
https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-desktop-bugs/suggestions/43779408-artwork-disappears-when-zoomed-in

Using the latest MBP (updated with latest OS) and most recent version of Illustrator 26.0.3

Comment: I can confirm about the same glitch with gray screen when zooming in InDesign (MBR M1 Pro, latest OS, latest CC).